# How to make debug true only for one app django

Tags: django

In django `DEBUG` turns debug on and off for the entire project. Is there a way to only debug one app and not the others?

To clarify by debug I mean when I get an error I get the error on the requested page. But when debug is off, you only get an error page (like 404 or 400).

Comment: if by "debug", you mean log at debug level: yes you can set different levels of logs in your settings

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the issue? You have to be more specific.

Comment: @Bilou06 clarified in the question

Comment: @Wtower I want to test a new app in production (with production database) and I want to find the bugs and the error page helps alot. I want to turn debug on without turning it on for the whole project.

Comment: So, you plan to make test on production ... You can use the log files or try to customize the error view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Django is capable to distinguish debug mode based on apps in a project. You can find more information on the debug mode on [Django docs: settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#debug).

The reason for this, I believe, among others, is that it is not a good practice to perform debugging on a live production server. The proper thing to do is to download a copy of the project local, do all your testing and then carefully apply any new changes to live.

In this way, you can be sure that you do not mess with something that works, and also be sure that all debug error reports are helpful to you.

Apart from that, as @Bilou06 suggested, there are different log levels as you can see in [Django docs: Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/). This can be helpful to you in that, if you insist with live experiments, you can have all relevant error pages emailed to you without activating debug mode.

More specifically, in order to have even 4xx emailed to you, you can add `django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` in your middleware, as the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/error-reporting/#errors) recommends.

Comment: I know it's not recommended to live test on production but I haven't launched yet and I don't want any one that stumbles upon my site to see error if they type anything in front of the domain. example.com/notfound shows a full on error page and I don't want that but I don't want to not have error either.

Comment: I understand that you have your reasons, nevertheless I have to stress this out for any other that may come across this in the future!